# Remove space in the middle of a string with $.trim?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want remove the space in the middle of a string with `$.trim()` for example:

```
console.log($.trim("hello,           how are you?       "));
```

I get:

```
hello,           how are you?
```

how can I get

```
hello, how are you?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this ==>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use regular expression to replace all consecutive spaces `\s\s+` with a single space as string `' '`, this will eliminate the spaces and keep only one space, then the `$.trim` will take care of the starting and/or ending spaces:

```
var string = "hello,           how are you?       ";
console.log($.trim(string.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')));
```

Comment: thanks, and happy new year to all!

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to use javascript `replace`.

I recommend you to use `regex`.

```js
var str="hello,           how are you?       ";
str=str.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' );
console.log(str);
```

Another easy way is to use `.join()` method.

```js
var str="hello,           how are you?       ";
str=str.split(/\s+/).join(' ');
console.log(str);
```